# Quartz.NET three level architecture С#

Tags: c#, quartz.net

There is a class that is inherited from the IJob interface. An instance of this class is created by implementation of the interface. In the constructor of this class, I call a method to for quartz start
`ExecuteTimeBuilder.Start();`

```csharp
public class CalculateManager : ICalculateManager, IJob
    {
        private readonly IStrongDataRepository _strongDataRepository;


        public CalculateManager(IStrongDataRepository strongDataRepository)
        {

            _strongDataRepository = strongDataRepository;

            ExecuteTimeBuilder.Start();
        }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HelloJob is executing.");
        }
```

Method .Start()

```csharp
public static async void Start()
        {
            IScheduler scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            await scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<CalculateManager>()
                .Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()  
                .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")     
                .StartNow()                           
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x           
                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)    
                    .RepeatForever())         
                .Build();        
            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);   
        }
```

The Execute method just doesn't start work. This is console application .Core 3.0 Interfaces are registered in the custom StartUp class

```csharp
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLogging();
            services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(Configuration);

            services.AddSingleton<IStrongDataRepository, StrongDataRepository>();

            services.AddSingleton<ICalculateManager, CalculateManager>();

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }
```

Why my method Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) doesn't show signs of life. It doesn't call.

Comment: What happens if you do `await scheduler.Start();` as the last command of `Start()`?

Comment: Create special CalculateJob and add ICalculateManager in that job. Second problem is that you must add CalculateJob to dependency injection (services.AddSingleton<CalculateJob>();)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working cuz I call it on another instatnce where the consctructor is empty. I need a reflection and call my method in other instatce. It is work